# Bootstrap toggle button theme, button text and div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

OK I have THREE count them (3) things I want to toggle using a Javascript or Jquery using bootstrap.

[Fiddle not working](http://jsfiddle.net/DivineChef/4xEPr/18/) CAN SOMEONE TELL ME WHY I got it to work locally and online.

[JavaScript does work here in this example](http://triplewww.com/cm/bs/template_toggle.html)

Javascript

```
    function toggleLink(obj)
    {
        var idCount = obj.id;
        idCount = idCount.replace( new RegExp('cont', 'g'), '');

        var elem = document.getElementById("show"+idCount);

        var hide = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).display =="none";
         if (hide) {
             elem.style.display="block";
        } 
        else {
           elem.style.display="none";
        }
    }
```

Simple CSS

```
[id^="show"] {
display: none;
 }
```

HTML

```
   <button class="btn btn-primary" id="cont1" href="javascript:void(0)" 
   onclick="toggleLink(this)">More </button><P><P>

   <div id="show1">
   CONTENT AREA #1</div><P><P>

   <button class="btn btn-default" id="cont2" href="javascript:void(0)"   
   onclick="toggleLink(this)">More </button><P>

  <div id="show2">
  CONTENT AREA #2<p></div>
```

So what this does now is toggle the visibility of the DIV beginning with "show(i)" from any button or link with the beginning "cont(i)"

I want the following 3 things to toggle:

1. Toggle the content
2. Change the label or Text of the button from "More" to "Less"
3. Assign a different bootstrap button theme (default, primary, whatever)

Got a start any help much appreciated. TIA.

Comment: to work on fiddle change the load of js to "No Wrap - in <head>", and don't work because when your html code was created the function do not exist.

Comment: I ever prefer the [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com) for me is much better than jsfiddle.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you don't botter to use jquery, because I made a sample using it, [take a look](http://jsbin.com/nepaw/1/watch?html,js,output)

The main piece that you need to pay attention is the follow code that are inside the `toggleLink()` function:

```
  if($(obj).text()==='More'){
      $(obj).text("Less");
      $(obj).attr("class","btn btn-primary");
  }else{
      $(obj).text("More");
      $(obj).attr("class","btn btn-default");
  }
```

I'm using two functions of jquery:

- `text()`: Used to change the text inside a html element, this only put text no more;
- `attr()`: Change any attribute of an html element;

I hope this help you!